# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve` npm ERR! vuedirectory@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`

Tags: django, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, django-3.2

I installed django with vuejs. i got this error:

```
 npm run serve

> vuedirectory@0.1.0 serve djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'vuetify' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vuetify' of undefined
    at djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/index.js:29:54
    at djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:26)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:272:48)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:132:25)
    at serve (djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:75:31)
    at Service.run (djangoprojectdirectory/vuedirectory/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:262:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vuedirectory@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuedirectory@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-24T11_16_58_764Z-debug.log
```